# Where to put custom gen.Tasks in Tornado?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I'm trying to run a `while` loop in Tornado while keeping the WebSocketHandler open. I've tried to implement gen.Task:

```
class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    count = db.my_collection.count() - 1
    cursor = coll.find(tailable=True, await_data=True, skip=count)

    (...)

    @asynchronous
    @gen.engine
    def run(self):
        doc = yield gen.Task(curse)
        self.render(doc)

    def curse(self):
        while WSHandler.cursor.alive:
        try:
            doc = WSHandler.cursor.next()
            return doc

    def render(doc)
        for c in WSHandler.connections:
            c['id'].write_message(doc)
```

So, beside keeping the `WebSocket` open, `WSHandler` also has these other custom functions. I need to run a constant loop (`curse(self)`) to tail the cursor of the mongodb - and asynchronously, so it doesn't block the `WebSocketHandler`.

Is my setup wrong? Should I put those functions somewhere else? (Where?) How can I run the infinite `while loop` and keep open `WebSocketHandler` at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using PyMongo, [which blocks](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7/faq.html#how-can-i-use-pymongo-with-an-asynchronous-socket-library-like-twisted). The `while` loop also blocks; putting it in a `gen.Task` doesn't help that in any way. `gen.Task` is just sugar for callbacks; it's basically another way of writing:

```
def run(self):
    doc = self.curse(callback=self.render)
    self.render(doc)

def curse(self, callback=None):
    while self.cursor.alive:
        doc = self.cursor.next()
        callback(doc)
```

Tornado is already an infinite while loop; you can't really have another one in a Tornado app, nor should you. What you can do is use an asynchronous db client (like asyncmongo, for example), which should allow you to simply:

```
cursor = coll.find(tailable=True, callback=render, ...)
```

and have your callback method fire when a document is received.